# Defining a new instance of a RadarCursor class in amCharts 4 vs amCharts 5

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

I am using amCharts for quite some time. In the past I have developed some Angular components using amCharts 4. Currently I am trying to upgrade them to amCharts 5. Throughout this process, some questions about the purpose behind the suggested changes have arisen. I' d like to share one of them.

**In amCharts 4,** to add a chart cursor to their chart, one had to create an instance of the class `RadarCursor` ([amCharts 4 Documentation - RadarCursor](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/radarcursor/)) and assign it to `chart.cursor` using the following line:

```
chart.cursor = new am4charts.Radar();
```

The `RadarCursor` class was defined in the file `RadarCursor.d.ts`, had an empty constructor and extended the class `XYCursor`.

**In amCharts 5**, to add a chart cursor to their chart, one has to do the following:

```
chart.cursor = am5radar.RadarCursor.new(
    root, 
    {}
)
```

where `root` is being defined using:

```
let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain the logic behind this new paradigm. I suspect that it still has to do with creating an instance of the `RadarCursor` class, but I haven't found anything related to this pattern in the official Typescript Documentation. Also this root parameter is somehow confusing, especially given the fact that no constructor is being defined in the file `RadarCursor.d.ts`.